# Receiving notification payload while App is active

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

We are integrating OneSignal with our project. The way we initialize is

```
[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:@"XXXXX" 
      handleNotificationReceived:^(OSNotification *notification) {
      } handleNotificationAction:^(OSNotificationOpenedResult *result) {
          OSNotificationPayload* payload = result.notification.payload;
          NSLog(@"Title = %@ and data = %@",payload.title,payload.additionalData);
      } settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : @(OSNotificationDisplayTypeNone), kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : @NO}];
```

Then from ViewController.m

```
[OneSignal registerForPushNotifications];
```

We don't want to show the in app alert box so we have set the OSNotificationDisplayTypeNone

Now life is good if we receive notification when App is not active, didReceiveRemoteNotification gets called and we handle the payload.

Problem is when app is active, in that case neither didReceiveRemoteNotification not the handler gets called. We want to flash certain things when app is active and notification is received. How do we achieve this ?

Comment: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` should be called doesnt matter your app is active or background, not sure why it doesnt get called, try show it's code here

Comment: [`didReceiveRemoteNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc) get called when app is Active, while [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc) gets called when in background.

Comment: how does registering your app for push notifications go? Do you receive a `deviceToken`?

Comment: @iphonic i think this is the reason, you should post it as answer

Comment: No it's not what @iphonic is saying. The first is the deprecated (but still functioning) delegate method, the second is the new delegate method. The `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` or the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` should be called always when you receive a remote notification...

Comment: application:didReceiveRemoteNotification or the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHand‌​ler: should be called always when you receive a remote notification - You are right. This is what apple doc says and how it used to behave earlier. Don't know if it is some problem with OneSignal.

Comment: Yes registering went well. I got deviceToken. As I said, notification works when app is not in foreground. Problem is when app is active.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the [latest OneSignal 2.2.2 iOS SDK](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases), this version fixes cases where the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHand‌​ler:` selector may not fire.

It is also important to call `[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions...]` from your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` selector in your `AppDelegate.m`. Calling this outside of it can cause the OneSignal SDK to miss events and your `handleNotificationReceived` block may not fire when it should.